# Is it possible to create a new revision using google apps script or google drive api?

Tags: google-drive-api, revision

Searched a bunch and found pages regarding list/get/update revisions, but nothing about actually making a new revision.
Instructions made it sound like if I set published: true in the requestBody it would create a new revision for the current state of the file.
Wrote some quick test code in node:

```
async function testGlg() {
await setupGoogleAuth()
const fileId = '1mVYwVAjDVcR-0bvxLaHzdToy6gx38B5Oe4CZhnRJuJo'
const r = await drive.revisions.list({
    fileId: fileId,
})
const revisions = r.data.revisions
const latestRevisionId = revisions[revisions.length-1].id
const w = await drive.revisions.update({
    fileId: fileId,
    revisionId: latestRevisionId,
    requestBody: {
        published: true,
    },
})
```

but that didn't appear to do anything. Also, I couldn't find a way to get the name of a revision as it's displayed in chrome or to set it via the api.

Answer (score 1):

### The [Revisions API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions) returns you the history of changes performed on a document

- You cannot create a new revision with the `Revisions API`, since revisions are being created automatically in the background - as a response to a change in a document.
- You can edit the document either via UI or  - depending on the document type - with an API, like e.g. the `Google Sheets API` in case of spreadsheets

- The method [Revisions: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/update) allows you to modify how an existing revision shall be handled (e.g. either it shall be kept forever), but it does not change the revision content.

Comment: Is there a way to *cut* the doc at the current state so that any future changes make a new revision automatically? Also, I didn't see a way to change the name of a revision in the api.

Comment: A change of a document always makes new revisions automatically.